# Predicate Logic Quantifiers Question

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm kinda confused regarding predicate quantifiers.

Firstly, what's the difference between

$\forall x .Tourist(x)$ and $\forall x \in Tourists$

I mean I understand that the first is a predicate form and the second implies that it belongs in the Tourist set but is there a specific case I should be using each one?

Additionally is $\forall x.Tourist(x).\exists y.Country(y).Likes(x,y)$ the same as:

$\forall x\exists y.Tourist(x) \land Country(y) \implies Likes(x,y)$ ??

If not what's the difference?

I'm really struggling to understand these things.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $∀x ∈ \text {Tourists}$ is not *predicate logic*. In predicate logic we have *predicate symbols*, like $\text {Tourists}(x)$  and quantifiers : $∀$ and $∃$. We quantify variables occurring in formulas with predicate symbols : $∀x \ \text {Tourists}(x)$.

Comment: This according to the rules of the *syntax*. But "intuitively", they mean the same : "every object is a Tourist".

Comment: Regarding the formula, the "dot" is used as a parenthesis. Thus, again, the correct expression is the second one, with the $\land$.

Comment: But in math shorthand, we are used to write something, like $\forall n \in \mathbb N \ P(n)$. Here we use the set-name $\mathbb N$ instead of a *predicate symbol* : $\mathbb N(x)$.